# Enabling extensions - directory not found

Tags: extension, configuration

I am attempting to enable extensions on civiCRM 4.6.8 via WordPress 4.3.

When I go to administer - system settings - manage extensions I am told I need to set my Extensions Directory. I do so via my file manager at public_html/iowafarmersunion/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext, paste this file location into Civi, but them an told that the CiviCRM extension directory does not exist.

Am I skipping a step? I was following directly on this page: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions#Extensions-WordPress

Thank you!

edit:
I have made sure the directory's permissions are set to 777 for the time being and still no dice.

Comment: Did you leave off the opening slash?  You've left it off in the question above.

Comment: I did at first... whoops! Just added it and am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need an absolute path from the server's root (/), and I doubt that there's a directory /public_html in your setup.  More common situations are:

- /var/www/public_html
- /srv/www/yoursite/public_html
- /home/someuser/public_html

or something similar.

You can tell by looking in your `civicrm.settings.php` file that's in `wp-content/plugins/civicrm` and scrolling down to the file paths.  One of them will be to the `templates_c` folder, which should normally be in `wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm`.  That path will be all the way to the root of your server, so you can just copy that and replace `templates_c` with `custom_ext`.

Of course, you could also look at the Temporary Files and Custom Files fields in your Directories admin page.  Under normal circumstances, those should also be pointing to sibling folders of your `custom_ext` folder.

While you're at it, make sure you set the Extension Resource URL under *Administer - System Settings - Resource URLs*.  You can probably use the Image Upload URL as an example, replacing `persist/contribute` with `custom_ext`.

Now, why CiviCRM doesn't just create the extensions folder and record its location when installing is totally beyond me.